# How to view log of LOG(INFO) in android aosp

Tags: android, logging, android-source, logcat

Where can I view log of LOG(INFO), LOG(DEBUG),.. in android ? I have tried `adb logcat` and `dmesg` but I didn't see it in anyone!

```
...
#include <android-base/logging.h>
...
    LOG(INFO) << __func__ << " : Start HAL";
...
```

Comment: Maybe the size of your logbuffer is too small. Please check `adb logcat --buffer-size`. Does logcat show nothing at all? Not even with `adb logcat *:V`?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
<strike>I'm not sure about LOG(INFO)</strike>.  .  .    `adb logcat -b kernel`

Generally the ALOGx() macros are used on AOSP native.  By ALOGx I mean ALOGD , ALOGV etc.   And the messages can be seen via logcat

```
#include <log/log.h>

ALOGD("Hello log");
```

See this header for more details: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/master/liblog/include/log/log_main.h